# On the function $f\colon(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\rightarrow (-\infty,\infty)$ given by $x\mapsto 1+2x$

Tags: functions

> If $x\mapsto 1+2x$ is a function having $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ as domain and $(-\infty,\infty)$ as codomain then it is
>
> 1. onto but not one one
> 2. one one but not onto
> 3. one one and onto
> 4. neither one one nor onto
>
> *Solution*: It is one one.

I don't understand this solution, because I think that it is not onto, as $1000$ belongs to the codomain and $999/2$ does not belong to the domain.

Comment: A continuous function on $\mathbb R$ restricted to a bounded interval is bounded, so yes, it is not onto.

Comment: The "ans" is wrong: that function, with that domain and codomain, is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

This function is injective (one-to-one) as it preserves distinctness.
You can easily verify that if $a \neq b$ then $(1+2a) \neq (1+2b)$.

Then, it is not onto, and so it is not bijective too.
It would have been surjective if its codomain was defined as $(1-\pi, 1+\pi)$. But since the codomain is defined as $(-\infty, +\infty)$, there're obviously values from the codomain which the function does not take, e.g. the values -1000 or 1000, and so it is not surjective (i.e. is not onto).

See also:
[Injective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)
[Surjective function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function)